# What programming language will the lunar gateway run on? How much of its code will be inherited from existing ISS components?

Tags: space-station, software, flight-computer, lunar-gateway

What programming language will be used for the main elements of the lunar gateway?

Will programmatical components be inherited from the ISS? If so, to what extent?

Comment: Re the first question, *What programming language will be used for the main elements of the lunar gateway?* That's mostly proprietary information. The people who know the answer have signed disclosure agreements that prevent them from answering your question.

Comment: Re the second question, *Will programmatical components be inherited from the ISS?* Other than design concepts, I can only hope the answer is zero. The ISS is plagued with using what many describe as the premier "bondage and discipline" programming language, Ada.

Comment: @DavidHammen quite so. We have _modern_ plagues now, like javascript!

Comment: @StarfishPrime Javascript will almost certainly be one of the many programming languages used to support the Gateway. It might well be used as a front-end language for non-safety critical displays, both in space and in ground support.

Comment: To the OP: You are asking the question as if there will be One Language to rule them all. That will not be the case. Many programming languages will be used.

Comment: @DavidHammen for the core of the flight computer too? I would expect the main nodes' critical software to use the same language and compiler to avoid any potential discrepancies in the APIs

Comment: @Speedphoenix There will be multiple components of the Gateway, built by different prime contractors. Some of the components will be built in the U.S., others in Europe, with contributions from Japan and Canada. Those different components will not be calling functions on another components flight computers. They will be sending data between one another, not making API calls.